# How can i achieve dictionary type data access in Chromium embedded CEF1

Tags: chromium-embedded

I would like to achieve dictionary like data pattern that can be accessed from the
java script. Something like this:

pseudo Code:

```
 for all records:
 {
       rec  =  //Get the Record
       rec["Name"]
       rec["Address"]
 }
```

I am trying to achieve with CefV8Accessor, but i am not getting near to the solution.

Kindly provide few links for the reference, as i see the documentation is very less from chromium embedded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to create a JS "dictionary" object for CEF using C++. If so, here's a code snippet that does that:

```
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> GetDictionary(__in const wstring& sName, __in const wstring& sAddress)
{
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> objectJS = CefV8Value::CreateObject(NULL);
    objectJS->SetValue(L"Name", sName, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
    objectJS->SetValue(L"Address", sAddress, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
    return objectJS;
}
```

The *CefV8Accessor* can also be used for that matter, but that's only if you want specific control over the set & get methods, to create a new type of object.
In that case you should create a class that inherits *CefV8Accessor*, implement the Set and Get methods (in a similar way to what appears in the code above), and pass it to the *CreateObject* method. The return value would be an instance of that new type of object.

I strongly suggest to browse through [this link](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration), if you haven't already.